# WHERE Columnname from comboBox = value?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Iam trying to figure out a way to select a value on a comboBox which would then be used for and mysql command.

Iam new to coding in c# so i got know clue where my mistake should be.. searched some hours now and found nothing.

It is supposed to be used as an filter to search through a huge stack of customers data to for example only show customers living in Berlin, oder working as...

```
if (checkBoxrecruitingsearch2.Checked)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmddtschichten = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmddtschichten.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmddtschichten.CommandText = "SELECT id, Wohnort, Berufsbezeichnung FROM bewerber WHERE '"+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +"' = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + "' and '" + comboBoxrecruitingsearch2.Text + "' = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch2.Text + "'";
                cmddtschichten.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dtschichten = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter cmddaschichten = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmddtschichten);
                cmddaschichten.Fill(dtschichten);
                dtschichten.Columns["id"].ColumnName = "Bewerber ID";
                dtschichten.Columns["Wohnort"].ColumnName = "Wohnort";
                dtschichten.Columns["Berufsbezeichnung"].ColumnName = "Berufsbezeichnung";
                BindingSource bSourceschichten = new BindingSource();

                bSourceschichten.DataSource = dtschichten;
                dataGridViewrecruitingsearchresult.DataSource = bSourceschichten;
                cmddaschichten.Update(dtschichten);
            }
            else
            {
                MySqlCommand cmddtschichten = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmddtschichten.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmddtschichten.CommandText = "SELECT id, Wohnort, Berufsbezeichnung FROM bewerber WHERE '"+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +"' = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + "'";
                cmddtschichten.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dtschichten = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter cmddaschichten = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmddtschichten);
                cmddaschichten.Fill(dtschichten);
                dtschichten.Columns["id"].ColumnName = "Bewerber ID";
                dtschichten.Columns["Wohnort"].ColumnName = "Wohnort";
                dtschichten.Columns["Berufsbezeichnung"].ColumnName = "Berufsbezeichnung";
                BindingSource bSourceschichten = new BindingSource();

                bSourceschichten.DataSource = dtschichten;
                dataGridViewrecruitingsearchresult.DataSource = bSourceschichten;
                cmddaschichten.Update(dtschichten);
            }
```

the expected result would be to get back all "bewerber" where column (choosen on comboBoxrecruitingfilter) equals textBoxrecuitingsearch

I do get shown a list with all entry's when executing with empty text and combobox, otherwise it shows nothing

Comment: If I remember correctly mysql does have a specific column name delimiter " ` " but in your where you are using `" ' "`. Very similar but different characters... `WHERE ' "+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +" ' = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + " '`. Flagging for close as typo

Comment: so ` hm ? gonna trie that out, thanks. allready created many of those mysql request all with ' and they seem to work so far

Comment: yep, yep that was it. acctualy i did not realy believe that would help, but it did, thanks a lot @bradbury9

Comment: BTW, unless all your users are trusted, consider changing your code, you are open to SQL Injection attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

If I remember correctly mysql does have a specific column name delimiter " ` " but in your where you are using " ' ". Very similar but different characters

```
WHERE ' "+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +" ' = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + " '
```

should be:

```
WHERE ` "+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +" ` = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + " '
```

As a side note, your code is subject to SQL Injection, if your users are not trusted you have a security problem/could be hacked. Should move to parametrized queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'` around the field name in the where clause:

```
cmddtschichten.CommandText = "SELECT id, Wohnort, Berufsbezeichnung FROM bewerber WHERE "+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +" = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + "' and " + comboBoxrecruitingsearch2.Text + " = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch2.Text + "'";
```

and

```
cmddtschichten.CommandText = "SELECT id, Wohnort, Berufsbezeichnung FROM bewerber WHERE "+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +" = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + "'";
```

If you have space between your field names, you can use one of the following:

```
cmddtschichten.CommandText = "SELECT id, Wohnort, Berufsbezeichnung FROM bewerber WHERE `"+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +"` = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + "'";
```

or

```
cmddtschichten.CommandText = "SELECT id, Wohnort, Berufsbezeichnung FROM bewerber WHERE ["+ comboBoxrecruitingfilter.Text +"] = '" + textBoxrecruitingsearch.Text + "'";
```

Comment: If the combobox has spaces in its values the query would break. Better approach would be using the adecuate column delimiter.

Comment: Fair objection. Then you are correct. Then you can use ``` as you said or `[ ]`. Answer edited.